# Apply class to parents of child apart from the one selected - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, parent

Im trying to apply a class to every parent element of a child apart from the child I have selected.

```
 $('.myChildName').parents('.myParentName').toggleClass("applyStyle");
```

This applies the class to one I have selected, I want it to apply to every parent APART from this one. I believe i can use the :not selector but it doesnt seem to want to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all `.myParentName` then exclude the current parent

```
$('.myParentName').not($('.myChildName').parents()).toggleClass("applyStyle");// also $('.myChildName').closest('.myParentName') instead of $('.myChildName').parents()
```

Another way could be

```
$('.myParentName:not(:has(.myChildName))').toggleClass("applyStyle");
```